# Validación de email unico en Laravel Livewire

Tags: validación, laravel-livewire

Necesito profundizar en la validación de un **campo único en Laravel**, en mi caso con el **email**.

Sé que la siguiente funcionalidad debería funcionar en Laravel

```
'email' => 'unique:App\User,email',
```

Pero esta funcionalidad en el formulario Livewire no funciona en tiempo real. Al llegar al submit si el email es repetido me da el siguiente error:

> laravel Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry email
> unique

Desconozco la funcionalidad del mismo, suponía que esto evitaba el error y validaba que el mail sea unico en el formulario. Esto no es así ¿me estaría faltando algo?

O debo hacer la regla de forma manual?

```
$usuario = User::where('email', $email);
```

Agradezco mucho su tiempo destinado en mi consulta.

Comment: Pues ese mensaje producto del constraint en la bd indica que la validación (en tu bd funciona), otra cosa es como lo manejes en el front para avisarle al usuario

Comment: No lo coloques solucionado, con publicar tu respuesta alcanza

Comment: Perdón, aún sigo aprendiendo sobre la comunidad. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analizando la validación de Livewire encontré un método genial en tiempo real.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/input-validation

```
public function updated($field)
{
    $this->validateOnly($field, [
        'email' => 'unique:App\User,email'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no si si llegue algo tarde pero ojala le sirva a alguien.

Para cuando se crea un registro y quiere que sea único lo hago así

```
protected $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|min:3|email|unique:App\Models\User,email',
];
```

y utilizar este para la validación en tiempo real

```
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}
```

para hacer la validación cuando actualiza un registro unico puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma según como tengas en los $rules

En mi caso la hago así ya que manejo controlador distintos tanto para crear como para actualizar

```
function rules() {
    return [
        'user.email' => 'required|min:3|email|email|unique:App\Models\User,email,'. optional($this->user)->id,
    ];
}
```

Y para activa la validación en tiempo real se adiciona lo siguiente

```
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}
```